# Measurements on a unit circle

Tags: number-theory

Given a unit circle and a point $P_0$ on it, we call $i$-*step* ($i=1, 2, \ldots$) taking a point $P_i$ on the circle such that the arc lenght $P_{i-1}P_i=n\in\mathbb{N}$ (we use the convention of taking measurements anticlockwise).

- Prove/disprove that after a finite numbers of *steps* there aren't $i, j$ such that $P_iP_j>\alpha$, for every $\alpha\in(0, 2\pi)$.
- Fixed $\alpha$, determine the first $k$-*step* after that the previous statement is true (if it's true!). If it's not possible to determine *exactly* such $k$, give upper and lower bounds on it.

Edit: $n$ and $\alpha$ are fixed.

Comment: It would be nice of you to provide some context, for example, where does the problem come from, why do you want an answer, what progress have you made, where are you getting stuck, that sort of thing.

Comment: Is $n$ a fixed number?

Comment: I've got a problem with your quantifier order. The way I read it: $$\exists k\in\mathbb N\;\forall\alpha\in(0,2\pi)\;\nexists i,j\in\mathbb N: i,j\leq k, P_iP_j>\alpha$$ In words: no matter how small you choose $\alpha$, you will not be able to find any two points in the first $k$ points which are farther than $\alpha$ apart. This is certainly wrong, since you have a finite number of points, so you have a minimal arc length, so you can shoose $\alpha$ smaller than that.

Comment: The question comes from a problem that has nothing to do with this one. I've shown (with a computer) that the statement is true for $n=3$ and $\alpha=\pi/2$ (and I've shown also that $k=12$). So I thought that it would be nice to generalize this fact.
Yes, $n$ is fixed.
@MvG: $\alpha$ is fixed too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a consequence of the [equidistribution theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equidistribution_theorem). Your step is a fraction $n/2\pi$ of the circle, which is irrational, so the $P_i$ are uniformly distributed. Specifically for any $\alpha>0$ there is a $N(\alpha)$ that guarantees that after $N(\alpha)$ steps some $P_i$ falls in the arc $[\frac{i\alpha}{2},\frac{(i+1)\alpha}{2}]$ for every $0\le i < 4\pi/\alpha$ guaranteeing the maximum distance is at most $\alpha$.

The number of steps needed for a given $\alpha$ is related to the behavior discrepancy
$$
D(k) = \sup_{A}\left| \frac{\#\{P_i \in A\}}{k}-\frac{|A|}{2\pi}\right|
$$
where the $\sup$ is over all arcs $A$, $|A|$ is the arc length and $\#\{P_i\in A\}$ is the number of the first $k$ points that land in $A$. A theorem of Schmidt says that there are arbitrarily large $k$ such that $D(k)\ge \log k/25 k$, so in general you will need on the order of $\frac{1}{\alpha}\log \frac{1}{\alpha}$ steps.

I don't have a simple upper bound, but here are some references that deal with this problem:

- [Ramshaw: On the discrepancy of the sequence formed by the multiples of an irrational number](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0022314X81900020)
- Drmota & Tichy: Sequences, Discrepancies and Applications
- Kuipers & Niederreiter: Uniform Distribution of Sequences